# Append different geometry to layer within GeoPackage

Tags: qgis, geopackage

I have a layer with lines - I export it qith QGIS to a new geopackage. A second layer with the same table structure  but containing polygons should go into the same geopackage and preferably into the same layer. When i go on Export, select the geopackage and type in the same layer name as before, it asks me if i want to: Overwrite File, Overwrite Layer, Append to Layer or Cancel. I pick "Append to layer" but the result does not contain the polygons. Am i doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: well, QGIS splits the layer again into layers according to their geometry. I want them in one layer as the come from one and the same MapInfo .Tab file. But if there is no other way i can save them "splitted" into one gpkg, was just wondering why it is offering me the "append to layer" option then

Comment: The "append layer" let you add more line to your line layer (for exemple if you get a new line layer that you want to add to an already existing line layer)

Answer (score 2):

Depend on what your future use is but mixing geometry is generally not good practice (for exemple QGIS and Arcmap cant use layer with mixed geometry).

For your specific problem I think it came from the type of geometry of your line layer, when you export it you have the option to choose the geometry type (Automatic, Point, Linestring, polygon, GeometryCollection or No Geometry), if you let it as Automatic (the default) or choose linestring it is set as linestring and you cant add another type of geometry.

You should try to export again your line layer with the Geometry type : GeometryCollection then try to add your polygon.

Answer (score 1):

What you are wanting to achieve is associate multiple geometries of different types,  with a single feature.

First and formost, is language. 'Layer' here is - for this answer - an enduser interface inside of a GIS application which exposes geometry features. For this answer though, I talk mainly about the database backend and as such, use the phrase 'table'. That is - a database table.

Most (but not all) GIS databases and file formats are limited to scenarios of a single geometry column (and therefore geometry type ) per table.
Geopackages - being a relational database implementation - are able to implement models that allow for a single record requiring two different geometry representations. And there are plenty of valid scenarios where this might occur. Database view tables then help complete the solution.

Because each scenario is different, they may require different solutions, so this link here is really useful in working through different solutions.
https://www.geopackage.org/guidance/modeling.html

However for your specific scenario - I am going to assume a 1-n scenario. Table 1 will be your 'lines' layer, lets call it 'roads' just to be simple. Your second table will be the polygon layer, lets call it 'road_reserve'.

Then load your data into the two seperate tables. Youw ill need to create a new 'view' table in the Geopackage, which requires some SQL (and obviously some backend database access. Something similar to

```
CREATE VIEW roads_complete AS 
SELECT A.road_id, ST_GeomFromText('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(' || ST_AsText(A.geom) || ',' || group_concat(ST_AsText(B.geom)) ||')')  as geom
FROM roads as A 
JOIN road_reserve as B 
ON A.road_id = B.road_id
GROUP BY A.road_id;
```

(Note that im just copying this from the link above).
This will create a new view table called roads_complete, which will have both gometries. I think.

Then in QGIS, when you browse the database you will see something similar. (Note this is a picture ive scraped off the internet, simply showing the QGIS interface of a table which has multi-geometry types).

[image]

Note that these still get loaded into QGIS as two seperate *layers*. But the underlying attribute information for a single record, will be the same whether you select the polygon geometry, or the line geometry.

Setting this up is a little bit of effort and possibly not worth your time for simple data migration. Definitely good for longer term usage and more complex data modelling scenarios that have longevity. Good luck.